# how to get index of the element in focus for a horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

i have this horizontal scroll view in my code. This horizontalscrollview has a series of imageviews in it. Whenever i swipe my finger and the scroll moves from one image to another, i need to find the index of the view now in focus.
In short i need some way to identify which child element of the horizontalscrollview is in focus right now so that i can do stuff based on that.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

mHorizontalScroll.indexOfChild(mView);

//where mHorizontalScroll is name of scroll view and mView is name of child in focus.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve what you asked (i.e) index of the currently visible position by using Horizontal ScrollView... why not try **gallery**... you can use

```
mGallery.getSelectedItemPosition()
```

to obtain the currently selected position.